# I am trying to add routes on my google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to show routes on my google map... i am developing a cab booking App, in which i am getting two values "From" and "To" from the user, that where they want to go?

but i am facing the problems on adding routes in map...When i submit the value i got force closed...

Here is my coding informations...

**Dialogue.java class which is on the snap shot image**

```
public class Dialoge extends Activity{
    Button b;
    EditText e1,e2;

    String addressfrom,addressto;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.dia);
        e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.from);
        e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.To);

        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Submit);


        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(v==b){
                    addressfrom = e1.getText().toString();
                    addressto = e2.getText().toString();
                    Intent i = new Intent(Dialoge.this,RideNow.class);
                    i.putExtra("from", addressfrom);
                    i.putExtra("to", addressto);
                    startActivity(i);

                    /*String format = "geo:0,0?q="+addressto;
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(format); 
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);*/



            }
            }
        });


    }



}
```

**My RideNow.java job that shows route and being called when pressing Submit button**

```
public class RideNow extends Activity {
    GoogleMap mMap;
    String fromString,toString,url,polyline;
    double latitude,longitude,latitudeto,longitudeto;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    LatLng l,l2;
    double latt;
    List<HashMap<String, String>> path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String,String>>>() ;
    List<LatLng> list = null;
    PolylineOptions p = null;
    ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
    TextView t1,t2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ridenow);

        t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        t2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text2);

        MapFragment m = (MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);
        mMap = m.getMap();
        //mv.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());

        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle b = i.getExtras();
        fromString = b.getString("from");
        toString = b.getString("to");

        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(RideNow.this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            //########## Address From ###########
              List<Address> addressesfrom =
          geoCoder.getFromLocationName(fromString, 1); 
              if (addressesfrom.size() >  0) {
                 latitude = addressesfrom.get(0).getLatitude(); 
                 longitude =addressesfrom.get(0).getLongitude(); }

             //######### Address To ##########

              List<Address> addressesto =
                      geoCoder.getFromLocationName(toString, 1); 
                          if (addressesto.size() >  0) {
                             latitudeto = addressesto.get(0).getLatitude(); 
                             longitudeto =addressesto.get(0).getLongitude(); }

            l = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            l2 = new LatLng(latitudeto, longitudeto);
            url = getDirectionsUrl(l, l2);
            t1.setText(""+latitude+","+longitude);
            t2.setText(""+latitudeto+","+longitudeto);
            new json().execute();

            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(l).title(""+fromString);

            mMap.addMarker(marker);
            MarkerOptions markerto = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitudeto, longitudeto)).title(""+toString);
            CameraPosition cameraPositionto = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(latitudeto, longitudeto)).bearing(45).tilt(90).zoom(mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom).build();
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPositionto));
            mMap.addMarker(markerto);


            mMap.addPolyline(p);



          } catch (IOException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace(); }


    }
    private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;

        return url;
    }
    public class json extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);
            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            if(jsonStr!=null){
                try{
                    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    JSONArray jroute = jobj.getJSONArray("routes");


                        JSONObject j = jroute.getJSONObject(0);
                        JSONObject jbound = j.getJSONObject("bounds");
                        JSONObject jn = jbound.getJSONObject("northeast");
                        String d = jn.getString("lat");

                        JSONArray jlegs = j.getJSONArray("legs");
                        JSONObject jobjj = jlegs.getJSONObject(0);

                        JSONObject jduration =jobjj.getJSONObject("duration");


                        JSONArray steps = jobjj.getJSONArray("steps");
                        JSONObject jsteps = steps.getJSONObject(0);
                        JSONObject poly = jsteps.getJSONObject("polyline");
                        polyline = poly.getString("points");
                        list = decodePoly(polyline);
                        for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            hm.put("lat", Double.toString((list.get(l)).latitude) );
                            hm.put("lng", Double.toString((list.get(l)).longitude) );
                            path.add(hm);
                        }
                        points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                        for(int m=0;m<path.size();m++){
                            HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(m);

                            double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                            double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                            LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                            points.add(position);
                        }
                        //p.addAll(points);



                }catch(Exception e){}
                }
                return null;


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd = new ProgressDialog(RideNow.this);
            pd.setTitle("Please Wait....");
            pd.setMessage("Wait");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pd.dismiss();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," ("+polyline+")",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+latt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            p.addAll(points);
        }

    }
    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }
}
```

**My Logcat**

```
02-23 17:44:14.930: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:15.930: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:16.140: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:17.140: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:17.350: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:18.350: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:18.560: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:19.560: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:19.770: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:20.770: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:20.980: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:21.980: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:22.190: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:23.190: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:23.400: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:24.400: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:24.610: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:25.610: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:25.690: D/dalvikvm(950): GC_CONCURRENT freed 396K, 55% free 2671K/5831K, external 716K/1038K, paused 0ms+0ms
02-23 17:44:25.820: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:26.820: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:27.030: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:28.030: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:28.240: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:29.240: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:29.450: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:30.450: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:30.660: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:31.660: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:31.870: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:32.870: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:33.080: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:34.080: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:34.290: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:35.290: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:35.500: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:36.500: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:36.710: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:37.710: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:37.920: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:38.920: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:39.130: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:40.130: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:40.340: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:41.340: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:41.550: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:42.550: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:42.760: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:42.770: D/dalvikvm(2366): GC_CONCURRENT freed 384K, 54% free 2682K/5767K, external 716K/1038K, paused 0ms+0ms
02-23 17:44:43.760: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:43.970: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:44.970: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:45.180: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:46.180: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:46.390: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:47.390: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:47.600: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:48.600: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:48.810: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:49.810: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:50.020: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:51.020: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:51.230: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:52.230: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:52.440: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:53.440: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:53.650: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
02-23 17:44:54.650: W/PGA(521): ctlSwapBuffers(133): Host Connect failed, err = -1(0xffffffff)
02-23 17:44:54.860: E/PGA(521): PgaSocketWriteAllHdipc: hd_ipc_send() failed
```

Comment: add your logcat error.So some one can help you.

Comment: I've added my logCat... it seems like i dont get any error...@Ravi

Comment: when i add symple polyline between two markers...the programm runs properly...@Ravi

Comment: on which activity you got error either My RideNow.java class or Dialogue.java. you should debug your code and check on which line you got error.

Comment: i got the forced close on RideNow.java class

Comment: On which line you receive the error.

Comment: List<Address> addressesfrom =
          geoCoder.getFromLocationName(fromString, 1); 
              if (addressesfrom.size() >  0) {
                 latitude = addressesfrom.get(0).getLatitude(); 
                 longitude =addressesfrom.get(0).getLongitude();  may give error, if address is null.Are you testing in emulator?

Comment: No no m not running it on emulator @Ravi

Answer (score 0):

Your logcat shows that this is not a code error, Rather this is an emulator error on the PC. If you are running this code on the Bluestack Android Emulator you are likely to get this error in the logcat.

The only available solution for this problem is to quit the Bluestacks (which always runs in the background) the problem will be solved!!

Comment: No m not running it on bluestack m running on Gionee Android Phone...but its showing a bluestack error because i have installed in my lappy...@AniV

Comment: Than I would recommend you to uninstall the Bluestack and then run the program this would definitely solve the issue.